# Fetching 1 frames per second from a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to fetch 1 frame per second from a video. For example if there is a video of 32 seconds then I need 32 images of that video i.e. one image per second.

Answer (score 3):

> This will create one thumbnail image every second, named `out1.png`, `out2.png`,
>   `out3.png`, ...

```
ffmpeg -i input.flv -f image2 -vf fps=fps=1 out%d.png
```

[Create a thumbnail image every X seconds of the video](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video)

Comment: ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf fps=1 out%d.png from the link works!

Comment: this generally works but does not work if the video length is just over a sec ... e.g. 50.035sec (it ignores the last .035 secs and does not create a thumb for it) .... 50.7 works as expected